# extract $_POST data

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, post

I'm working on a project where I have retrieved the name and values from selected checkboxes using jquery/ajax. I have set the names and values of the checkboxes using php on the main page. I would like to extract the names using $_POST in a seperate php script so that I can use these names to delete projects out of MySQL.

```
$("#deleteproject").click(function () {
    var names = [];
    $('#projectcheckbox input:checked').each(function() {
        //all checkbox names are put in array
        names.push({name: $(this).attr('name'), value: $(this).val()});
    });
    alert($.param(names));
    return false;
});
```

The above alert($.param) returns the selected checkbox in a val1.name and val1.value format.

```
//run delete_project.php to erase projects from database
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:"delete_project.php",
    data: names,
    cache: false,
    success:function() {
        alert(names + ' deleted')
    }
});
```

I have searched for an answer the last couples days and I would appreciate some help figuring this out.

Comment: How are these two piece of JavaScript related? As written in this question, `names` in the click callback has nothing to do with `names` in the `$.ajax()` call. For that matter, why aren't you just [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)ing the form (presumably `#projectcheckbox`)?

Comment: right now I'm using the first part to get the names and values of the selected checkboxes then I intend to pass the data to a seperate php script using the ajax below. I was having issues getting all first script to return the correct names. Forgot to change include the second script in the onclick. what is the benefit of .serialize() over what I'm doing now?

Comment: Okay, so how exactly do you expect `names` in the `$.ajax()` call to be set? Once that click callback completes, `names` is gone.

Comment: just serialize the form and forget about the $.param stuff as Matt Ball suggested

Comment: I'll give that a try. How can I extract all the names and values on the php side?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get. You might have to learn a little about arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer using html part in this way first, cos it's more flexible and easy in your case;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="projectcheckbox[]" value="foo_project" />
<input type="checkbox" name="projectcheckbox[]" value="bar_project" />
...
```

Or printing out the db results at first;

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
   print '<input type="checkbox" name="projectcheckbox[]" value="'.$project.'" />';
}
```

Then calling `jQuery.serialize` will give you a data stuff like;

```
projectcheckbox[]=foo_project&projectcheckbox[]=bar_project ...
```

PHP part (after post);

```
foreach ((array) $_POST['projectcheckbox'] as $pro) {
   // do something with $pro = foo_project or bar_project etc...
   // THIS PART FOR SECURITY GUYS :)
   // BUT! DO NOT FORGET TO SECURE YOUR DATA ($pro) HERE!!!!!
}
```

Comment: Maybe because of no `htmlspecialchars()` or something. Not worth a downvote though. +1 from me